# ASP.Net Run action on dropdown box selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make it so when I select an item in my productionLineDropDown drop-down box it will disable certain selections in my machineListDropDown Drop-down box.

For example I choose "Long Sweep" it disables the ability for the user to choose value: "802501".

I have been trying to play with the SelectedIndexChanged but it does not cause any action to happen. I tested the code on page load and it works. I just need to know how to run an action off selecting a value in a drop down box.

```
 protected void productLineDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (productLineDropDown.SelectedValue == "Long Sweep")
            {
                //machineListDropDown.Items.FindByValue("802501").Enabled = false;
                ListItem i = machineListDropDown.Items.FindByValue("802501");
                i.Attributes.Add("style", "color:gray;");
                i.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
                i.Value = "-1";

            }
        }
```

Alternatively I have:

```
machineListDropDown.Items.FindByValue("802501").Enabled = false;
```

But as I mention above both the code seems to work on page_load, I am just unable to get it to run off selecting a value in my drop-down.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: you get any error something like that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable a dropdownlist item based on a user selection on another drop down in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114667/how-do-i-disable-a-dropdownlist-item-based-on-a-user-selection-on-another-drop-d)

Comment: While looking through the suggested post I realized I hadn't turned auto post back on. That fixed my issue.